# Facet filter in Views wrongly returns "No results"

Tags: 7, search

I'm running into a strange behavior with Search API and Facets API, and I hope someone can point what I'm doing wrong.

I am working in Drupal 7 with Views, Search API, Database Search (search_api_db), Facets API, and Search Facets (search_api_facetapi). My view is working fine otherwise: exposed filters and facet filters work fine in isolation.

The problem happens when I search using an exposed filter, and then try to narrow it with a facet filter.

First step: I search using a exposed filter (see image 1). I get 606 results which display fine.

[image: Step 1]

Then I try to narrow clicking "2" in the facet "Filter by level". The field level is an Integer, and is indexed by Search API as an Integer. Weirdly, I supposedly get 33 results (the View says "Displaying 1 - 20 of 33") but NOTHING gets displayed in the View body (the View says "No results"). Still, the pager at the bottom correctly indicates that there are 2 pages.

[image: Step 2]

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: The field "Composer" is indexed as Fullsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I was using `Indexed Node: Composer` for the exposed filter instead of `Search: Fulltext search` (the field composer was indexed as a fulltext index).